# How to add data from a stored procedure directly into a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I wanted to know how I can add data returned from a stored procedure directly into a dataGridview.

I'm creating an attendance system in C# and I was sending the `Class_Id` and `Sub_Id` back to the stored procedure via combobox so that I can I can only see the students that are present in a certain class for a certain subject but I don't know how to add the returned results directly into a dataGridView

[Attendance Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwqGb.png).

In the screenshot, I am sending back the `Class_Id` and `Sub_Id` so that It only shows me the students that have those id in the stored procedure.

I executed the query in the stored procedure and It showed me the students that had the `Class_id` and `Sub_Id` I specified.

[Stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO1JB.png)

Here is the screenshot for the code

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHJGT.png)

Comment: Nver post images of your code! Post the code. What do you mean by _add data .. directly into a DataGridView_ ? As opposed to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Adapter to fill the `DataTable` and add that `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`:

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
 {
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("StoredProcedureName", conn);
   adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@subid",SqlDbType.Int).Value= comboBox1.SelectedValue;
   adapter.SelectedCommand.Parameters.Add("@classid",SqlDbType.Int).Value=comboBox1.SelectedValue;
   adapter.Fill(result);
 }
 dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

If your @subid and @classid is `typeof int`, I think you need to convert your `ComboBox` value to `int`.
You can try with `Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Value)` or even better `int.TryParse(comboBox1.Value, out result)`

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter` is also `IDisposable` so should also be in a `using` block.

Comment: Well the IDs are already in INT but will this automatically fill the datagridview with the data returned from the stored procedure?

Comment: And also do I place this code after the code I've written in the button of the form?

Comment: It worked man. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

may be this can be helpful to you.. you can replace my query with your stored procedure

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server = ADITYA\CBOWR; database = adi; integrated security = true;")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim query As String = "Select * from address"
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = query
    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(query, con)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    con.Open()
    sda.Fill(ds)
    GridView1.DataSource = ds
    GridView1.DataBind()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Question is tagged C#, this answer is VB.net. Other tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are all `IDisposable` so each should be in a `Using` block.